# AWS EFS permission denied for users in too many groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, amazon-efs

EFS directories are not accessible to users in members of about 20 groups. We are using centos and sssd to sync with a Microsoft AD. I recreated the issue to demonstrate the problem.

- I added user test the to the group with access /efs/folder (testgroup)
- the user test had access to /efs/folder
- I added test to 16 other groups
- I removed user test from the testgroup  and waited for id test to show all the updated memberships without testgroup.
- test could not access /efs/folder
- I added test to testgroup
- waited for the groups to sync with id test
- test could not access /efs/folder

Comment: Isn't the 16 group cap a limitation in NFS generally?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware. I found this link http://www.xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/ and will post a solution if it works.